# How do I change Zod's array custom error?

Tags: typescript, zod

I am using Zod to validate my react-hook-form fields and I keep getting the predefined error of "Expected array, received null", but I want a more front-end friendly wording that I define. How do I set a custom message for this setup? See `promos` below, with corresponding output when submitted with no selections made to the "checkbox" array field..

**Code:**

```
    promotion: z.object({
        id: z.string().optional(),
        name: z.string({
                required_error: "A name is required.",
                invalid_type_error: "A name is required.",
            }).min(1, "A name is required.").max(150, "The name must be less than 150 characters."),
        email: z.string({
                required_error: "An email is required.",
                invalid_type_error: "This is an invalid email.",
            }).email().min(1, "An email is required."),
        promos: z.array( z.string({
                required_error: "A promotion selection is required.",
                invalid_type_error: "This is an invalid promotion selection",
            }).min(1, "A promotion selection is required.") ).min(1, "At least one promotion selection is required."),
    }),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a **global** custom ZodErrorMap in order to handle specific kind of issue behavior.
The scope is global.

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const customErrorMap: z.ZodErrorMap = (issue, ctx) => {
  if (issue.code === z.ZodIssueCode.invalid_type) {
    if (issue.expected === "string") {
      return { message: "bad type!" };
    }
  }
  if (issue.code === z.ZodIssueCode.custom) {
    return { message: `less-than-${(issue.params || {}).minimum}` };
  }
  return { message: ctx.defaultError };
};

z.setErrorMap(customErrorMap);
```

https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/blob/master/ERROR_HANDLING.md#customizing-errors-with-zoderrormap

If you want **less generic** usage, you can apply the customized ZodErrorMap to the **schema definition** or on the **schema parsing callback**.
But for schema application I think not all schema supports customized ZodErrorMap param.

### **UPDATED 2023-01-25**

Try using the following

```js
z.setErrorMap((issue, ctx) => {
  if (issue.code === "invalid_type" && issue.expected === "array")
    return { message: "Your array is not well defined" };
  return { message: ctx.defaultError };
});
```

Comment: Tried putting your code at the top level of my Next.js app with no luck and then tried right next to the schema definition and still didnt work :/ Is there a specific scope I need to put this snippet to work?

Comment: Did you try to test logging issue and ctx in the default custom error map? That way you can detect if the custom error map is detecting your array parsing issue and apply the right condition to it in order to handle correctly array errors?

Comment: Your updated code alone worked with just `setErrorMap` and returned your custom message when the array was submitted empty! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found no way to do this for arrays in zod, which is weird because it's possible for most other types.

There are two options around it.

### (1) Pass a default value

Ensure that `promos` always defaults to empty array.

```
.parse({...promotion, promos: promotion.promos ?? [] });
```

### (2) Manually rewrite validation errors

```
export const validateInput = <T>(
  input: Partial<T>,
  schema: z.Schema,
): Result<T, CustomError> => {
  const result = schema.safeParse(input); // returns object instead of throwing

  if (result.success) {
    return { data: result.data };
  }

  return {
    ...result,
    error: {
      issues: result.error.issues.map((error) => ({
        ...error,
        message: error.code === 'invalid_type' && error.expected === 'array' && error.received === 'null' ? "your message here" error.message
      }))
    }
  }; // or throw this result
};
```

EDIT: Then where you would normally call `schema.parse(input)` (to throw error) or `schema.safeParse(input)` (to return error), call the function above instead, throwing or returning as necessary.

Comment: Passing default value for my case won't work since the source needs to be more agnostic, but for the 2nd option, can you show how you'd use that in a schema? Would you just run that on a `refine()`?

Comment: edited the answer to be more clear. The function in case 2) replaces `.parse`. I could not solve you problem with `refine` for arrays. Might be a bug in zod.

Comment: Gotcha, well I am using react-hook-form library for my forms, and passing the schema validation directly to the form so there is no .parse call being made in my code, I would likely need to modify the react-hook-form usage.

Your first point did give me a small clue on a fix, I am simply passing an empty array to the react-hook-form initialization, which doesnt throw a specific error message, but at least it doesnt throw the `expected array, received null`, just throws a blank error message, which is better than using "array" and "null" for front end users.